# Indentation in MATLAB important?

Tags: matlab

I have written a code in MATLAB for university and I have been told that indentation is important and it caused me to lose 3 marks out of 8 for it. Is indentation not just "style"?

The code if as follows:

```
function[pp,pb,pd]=demopoly(fname,N)

%The function reads the data from the file and computes the coefficients of a polynomial of degree N of three polynomials pp, pb, and pd that best fit the population, births and deaths in the data.
%The function returns the three variables pp, pb and pd in this order.

C=csvread(fname);

pp=polyfit(C(:,1),C(:,2),N);

pb=polyfit(C(:,1),C(:,3),N);

pd=polyfit(C(:,1),C(:,4),N);

end
```

Can someone let me know where the indentations should have occurred?

Comment: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/case-and-space-sensitivity.html - "*MATLAB code is [...] insensitive to blank spaces except when defining arrays.*"  I suspect you got marked down because your code was difficult to read.

Comment: Indentation for the purposes of styling alone is extremely important. Don't underestimate the importance of readability.

Comment: Important for what? Makes no difference in how the code executes, but using good code formatting (using proper indentation, comments, etc.) makes code much easier for people other than yourself to read, and makes it easier for you to read when you come back after days, months, years of not seeing it.

Comment: Your question is not important. The important thing is that you start programming and you will understand this and other "rules" by yourself.

Comment: Wouldn't this be best answered by the people grading your work?

Comment: Indentation for readability is important, but I think in this case it's pretty harsh to lose 3 marks out of 8 for it. Your function is only a few lines long and is perfectly readable right now. With something longer, yes, make sure it's readable, and indentation is one important part of that. If I was being picky I'd be more concerned about you not putting spaces either side of `=` and after the main `,`s between arguments. And not splitting that long comment up into multiple lines. Might as well learn good practices early on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indentation is just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>  and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> away. Seems difficult? Other answers have pointed out why indentation is important. Regarding the question where indentation should have occured, the fact is ***there's no indentation problem in the code that you showed***.

If I had to cut your marks for the code you showed, I'll cut for:

- Having no line breaks in that first comment. It's too long and requires scrolling to read.
- Extra line breaks in code.

Answer (score 2):

Although Matlab code is not sensitive to indendation (unlike, for example, [Python](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/block_indentation.hawk)), it's very important to use a indentation in order to improve the code readability and it's [maintainability](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134855/what-characteristics-or-features-make-code-maintainable).

If you are too lazy to manually indent your code while writing it down, Matlab offers you a `Smart Indent` function that you can apply to your files once they are completed (more info [here](https://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2009/05/11/keep-your-code-readable-with-smart-indenting/)). If you are too lazy even for a `CTRL+A` `CTRL+I`, you could write a small "batch script of madness" that applies the `Smart Indent` to all the `.m` files located within a specific folder:

```
files = dir(fullfile(folder,'*.m'));

for i = 1:numel(files)
    file_name = files(i).name;
    file_path = fullfile(folder,file_name);

    file_handle = matlab.desktop.editor.openDocument(file_path);
    file_handle.smartIndentContents()
    file_handle.save()
    file_handle.close()
end
```

This is how I would format (and optimize a little bit) your function:

```
% The function reads the data from the file and computes
% the coefficients of a polynomial of degree N of three
% polynomials (pp, pb, and pd) that best fit the population,
% births and deaths in the data.

% The function returns the three variables pp, pb and pd
% in this order.

function [pp,pb,pd] = demopoly(fname,N)

    C = csvread(fname);
    C_1 = C(:,1);

    pp = polyfit(C_1,C(:,2),N);
    pb = polyfit(C_1,C(:,3),N);
    pd = polyfit(C_1,C(:,4),N);

end
```

Comment: You should put the comments back underneath the function header, so they are picked up by the command `help demopoly`.

Comment: Well, I normally use that approach to give a hint on the input and output arguments of the function itself. It's pretty nice. If you want to perform real comments, you have to put them inside the function, of course! Thanks!